# Prove that variable projection is recursive

Tags: computability, primitive-recursion, recursion-theory, mu-recursion

Let $\varphi:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}^*$ be an arbitrary recursive enumeration of finite strings and 
$\mathcal{I}^n_i(x_1,...,x_n) = x_i $
be the $i$-th projection over $n$ variables.

I would like to show **from the point of view of recursion theory** that the "variable" projection 
$$ (n,y) \mapsto \mathcal{I}_y^{\text{len}(\varphi(n))}(\varphi(n)) $$
is recursive.

Using TMs this is quite straightforward: just simulate the TM that computes $\varphi$ and print only the $y$-th term of that TM executed with input $n$.  I am interested in a purely "recursion-theoretical" proof, i.e., I would like to know how that function can be written in terms of primitive recursion and/or $\mu$-recursion, which I'm finding tricky.

Comment: I believe this depends on how do you actually formalize "$\varphi$ is recursive". Since this returns a variable-length sequence, and not a single natural, the basic definition of recursive function is no longer applicable. So, how do you choose to formalize that in recursion theory (without TMs)?

Comment: It can't be recursive because if $y > len(\varphi(n))$, it's undefined.

Comment: @xavierm02 Good catch. I guess one would have to default to $n$ or $1$ in that case.

Comment: @chi good point.The basic idea is that $\varphi$ is an effective enumeration of the (finite) strings, i.e. is a bijection and we can compute explicitly the index of each string in finite time (and viceversa). I know, this is actually a TM definition. For the purpose of the question I'm not sure whether it's really necessary to explicitly write $\varphi$ (after all, this "variable projection" returns just a number). Maybe we can rephrase the OP asking whether $\psi:\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ that maps $(n,y)$ to the $y$-th symbol of the $n$-th string is recursive.

Comment: @xavierm02 recursive doesn't mean total. If $y>len(\varphi(n))$ it can be undefined but still recursive, i.e. partial recursive. In case you want it to be total, some modifications as the ones suggested by Raphael should work.

Comment: Without a precise definition of $\varphi$ (or of it being effective) it seems hard to prove something useful precisely. E.g. assume $n$ is the index for some nonempty string. Can we effectively compute its length from $n$? Its first component (head)? The enumeration of the tail? These are basic algebraic operations on strings, which however might turn to be non recursive for "bad" choices of $\varphi$. Once you have head,tail, and a nonemptiness check, you can dissect the string by recursion and you should be able to compute your wanted function.

Comment: I don't think a definition of $\varphi$ is actually needed, but we need some assumption on it to be sure it is effective (in the TM sense). Emptiness can be checked since there's only a single index for the empty string. If we can assume e.g. that $\varphi^{-1}(head(\varphi(n)))$ is recursive, and its $tail$ analogous, I think we have all we need.